# Insert checkmark to PHPExcel object

Tags: php, character, phpexcel

I'm trying to add a checkmark to a cell in an excel file I'm creating using PHPExcel.

[Check mark info](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2713/index.htm)

However, I can't make it work. I'm using notepad++ and cannot copy+paste the check mark symbol. I tried using the UTF-8 hex value `\xE2\x9C\x93` but I just get a box in excel.

Does anyone know the proper way of doing this?

UPDATE:
The cell shows a box, but if the I look at the editor on the top (where 'fx' is), it shows the check mark. If I copy it and paste it here, it shows up the check mark. Is this a formatting error?

Comment: Are you sure that the cell is formatted with a font that supports this character? That's usually the reason you will see a box - it's the `symbol not supported` character.  See http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2713/fontsupport.htm

Comment: @Floris if I copy it manually it shows up fine. So that means, it should be supported, right?

Comment: Yes it would... Have you tried looking at the raw data in the file (close the file, rename it with `.zip` extension, then open the zip file and you can navigate to the raw xml.) Can be very instructive to compare "a good cell" and "a bad call" in that way.

Comment: @Floris Renamed it to a .zip file but it won't open. It says the compressed zip folder is invalid. Opened it with notepad and it just shows a bunch of characters with my data on it. But not in XML format. Tried renaming it to .XML and I get the same result.

Comment: Was it an `.xlsx` file to begin with? This trick doesn't work with `.xls` files... I should have mentioned that. Do a "save as..." if needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally figured out how to do it,

I set the font to Wingdings 2 and the letter 'P' will show up as a checkmark.

Comment: "formatted with a font that supports this character"... I think I should get some kudos. :-) Glad you figured it out! And very good that you actually bothered to return and give the answer - thanks for that.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of entering the UTF-8 hex value, simply enter the actual checkmark character: **✓**

Like so:

```
$sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(2, 1, '✓');
```